# java_home directory is not correct though it exists in my environment file

Tags: java

I'm using Java jdk with Maven and I have the following /etc/environment

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"

# Maven Settings
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.25/
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.3
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

The /usr/local/jdk1.6.25 does exist, but when I run mvn -version I get...

```
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 17:31:09+0000)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.6.0_23, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.0.0-14-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

does anyone know why this does not think my java_home directory is correct even though it exists in my environment file?

Comment: you're abusing the `/etc/environment` file, it should be written in conf format (see [the EnvironmentVariables page on help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)), as no shell expansion is available - you're variables will never get evaluated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple ideas... First, just to reformat for readability, this is your PATH

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

These are your env vars:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.25/
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.3
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

Note that "java" (the program) is in `$JAVA_HOME/bin`, not `$JAVA_HOME`.  That will cause a little confusion when a different 'java' is found in the shell's PATH.  For example...

```
$ type java
java is /usr/bin/java
```

So just modify your PATH:

```
$ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
$ type java
... should be $JAVA_HOME/bin/java ...
```

But I don't think that's the issue. From the mvn shell script launcher,

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
  echo "Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set."
fi
```

This would imply the var really isn't set -- not merely set to a wrong value. Perhaps this is the key hint:

> [my java_home ...] even though it exists in my environment file?

Perhaps you added/modified `JAVA_HOME` to `.bashrc` or `.profile` , and then in the same shell tried to run `mvn -v` ??  If so, these values won't be picked up until you source the file (e.g., `. ~/.bashrc` ) or create a new login shell (`bash -l`) in order for these env var's to be set (or reset).

(Also... it's just a matter of opinion, but in your `PATH`, I'd leave the standard `/usr/bin` (and `/usr/sbin` and `/bin`) in front of any `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/bin` (etc), just to avoid any rouge 'local' programs taking precedence over the standard programs... using something like `alternatives` would be preferable to override the default versions of standard applications.)